# Smoothly movement

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I want to make movement while button is clicked : left.
This is for mobile movement...

The problem its its move, but only once. I need to spam clicking button...

Code:

In create :

```
this.buttonleft.inputEnabled = true;
this.buttonleft.events.onInputDown.add(this.clickMoveLeft, this);
this.buttonleft.mouseDownCallback = false;

this.buttonleft.alpha = false; // Making no visable
```

Under everything - separate function :

```
clickMoveLeft: function()
{
    if(!this.clickMoveLeft.mouseDownCallback)
    {
        this.player.body.velocity.x = -160;
        this.buttonleft.mouseDownCallback = true;

    }
    else if (!this.clickMoveLeft.mouseUpCallback) 
    {
        this.player.body.velocity.x = 0;
        this.buttonleft.mouseDownCallback = false;
}
```

Comment: You mean when you click to a button, a "shape" will be moved left, then right. then jump and repeat all over again ? But when it will stop?

Comment: When i click left then sprite is moving once. (160) and i need click so many times to moving. I want to get result like ; i click and hold to button and sprite is moving until i dont hold button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the phaser framework but, knowing how js events works and after a [quick search in the docs](http://phaser.io/learn/chains) I'm pretty sure that the .mouseDownCallback callback is fired just once when you click the mouse and isn't continuos.
So you can use the mousedown event to call a function that keep moving what you want to move and the mouseup to stop it.